# Parse data from string "name:john email:john@example.com id:123456"

Tags: php, string, parsing

Basically, what I want is to access the data between substrings (between "name:" and "email:", for example)

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using that format for data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can first explode on space...

```
 $array  = explode(' ',$string);
```

and then explode on : while looping through....

```
 foreach($array as $arr){
     $temp = explode(':',$arr);
     echo $temp[1]; // your value here 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $tbl = 'name:john email:john@example.com id:123456';
    preg_match_all('/(name|email|id)\:([a-z0-9@_\-\.]+)/i', $tbl, $matches);
    print_R($matches);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name:john
            [1] => email:john@example.com
            [2] => id:123456
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => email
            [2] => id
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => john
            [1] => john@example.com
            [2] => 123456
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `name` component doesn't contain any spaces (since spaces are used as delimiters in the string), then [`sscanf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) is a perfectly suited native function.  `sscanf()` also has the added feature of being able to cast numeric substrings as integers or floats depending on the placeholder used.  `%s` represents a "no-whitespace" substring.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wev1a))

```
$string = 'name:john email:john@example.com id:123456';

var_export(sscanf($string, 'name:%s email:%s id:%d'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'john',
  1 => 'john@example.com',
  2 => 123456,
)
```

---

Alternatively, you can assign individual variables instead of returning an array:

```
sscanf($string, 'name:%s email:%s id:%d', $name, $email, $id);
```